# UPDATED: How to store previous calculation from form input?

Tags: javascript, html

**What is the problem (code) about?**

I have to make a form where the costumer can enter quantity, orderdate and delivery and then by clicking a button he will get his price.

Now the price depends on the quantity, order date and delivery.

Quantity discount:

He gets a discount of 2.5% if he orders more than 10 items (q > 10) and 
he only gets the discount on the extra items he orders. 
If he orders less that 10 then he just pays quantity*341, where 341 is the price of one item.

Order and delivery discount:

If he orders on a Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday AND the delivery takes 2 days or more then he gets a discount of 5%.

Comment: I fixed up your code a bit, but note - `<p1>` isn't a valid HTML element, and to properly indent your code you need to either select it and press command-K, or click the code indentation button in the toolbar

Comment: thank you. I have managed to fix the code and now I get the right result when I click the button "Calculate price". My problem now is how can i store this value, such that each time a consumer changes input in the form and calculates the new price he can see the old price?@luka

Answer (score 0):

```
dDiscount==0;
```

should be

```
dDiscount = 0;
```

Also you missed a semicolon, this:

```
total = q * 341 - qDiscount - dDiscount
```

should be this:

```
total = q * 341 - qDiscount - dDiscount;
```

(your day checking code looks ok...)

Answer (score 0):

you have this problem becasuse the function getday() return the present day and when you do var Dday = (day == 1) || (day == 2)|| (day == 3);
the condition is false so the result is NaN. You need create a function conditional for the day. For example declare the days where is present the discount of 25% and the days of 5%.